# How to configure HTTPS for node js with NGINX in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, nginx, https

I have to write some of configuration code but it does not work.So what i do for fix this issue

```
   server {
  listen       3000;
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  localhost;

        ssl_certificate  /nginx-1.15.12/ssl/server.crt; // own certificate
        ssl_certificate_key /nginx-1.15.12/ssl/server.key; //own privatekey
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://10.0.0.4:3000;  //my local IP with node js running port number
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  location /public {
    root C:\Program-Files\iisnode\www\RSRK_BETA; // path of my node js application
  }

}
```

I want to Run HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;   
    server_name localhost;
    ssl_certificate     /path/to/cert-storage/cert-self-signed.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert-storage/cert-self-signed.com.key;    
... 
    } 

}
```

I am running Node 10 + NGINX, on Linux. I am not sure that operating system should make a difference for NGINX itself. This is all I have, besides `location` settings, and it works.

Comment: Also, I suggest using Cloudflare as proxy, besides having cool free features, such as provideing an extra security layer, or static file caching, it also SSLs traffic to and from the client for you, with a maintenance-free self-renewing, Cloudflare certificate, while CF itself is ok with you using a self-signed, even outdated certificate, forever. This gets SSL sorted out very well, for good.

Comment: i have own certificate .not a self signed certificate

Comment: Whether you have an "official" certificate, not a self-signed one, does not really matter here. The point of my comment was, how your life could be easier, even with self-signed. And the point of my answer is, you could start with a simple configuration (auch as rhe one which works for me), to rule out possible errors and gradually add on needed parameters, once you are up and running.